# How to read a system file in android?

Tags: android, file, system

I want to read "build.prop" file from android's system folder and display it to a textview as a string. But, my app is running and then force closes ..

My code:

```
public void selfDestruct(View view) throws IOException {
    File path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(path, "build.prop");

    int length = (int) file.length();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    try {
        in.read(bytes);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }

    String contents = new String(bytes);

    textView.setText(contents);
}
```

Comment: A stacktrace would be helpful. Though, most likely, if your device is not rooted, your application does not have permission to read an android system folder.

Comment: Thanks for answering! How combine root with this fuction. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @VasylGlodan Well, basically if you dont know what build.prop file is, is a file that contains basic info about your phone, and it is located at /system. I just want to find a way by compining root process or not to read this file to a string.

Comment: So, I guess [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) or using a `Process` to execute `getprop` is not sufficient? However, If you root your device and grant root access to your application then you should be able to read the file with a `FileInputStream(new File("/system/build.prop"))`